# How to write python expression to filter out certain strings

Tags: python, regex

There is a string consisting several numbers, for example:

```
12.03 5.897 7.10.74 0.103 12.05 6.4.1 8.98
```

I want to use **Python regular expression** to output only those numbers with ONLY `single dot (.)`, such as `"12.03"` and `"5.897"`, not `"7.10.74"` and `"6.4.1"`.

I know this is a trivial question without regex, I just want to solve this with regex. But I really couldn't figure out how to solve this with regex. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you _need_ a regex? It's trivial without one.

Comment: No, i don't need one. But I just wanna solve it with regex.

Comment: Seems like a silly request. Writing the regex will taken (and ostensibly has taken) longer than the trivial (and more efficient!) solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But i just want to practice my regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a pure regex solution then use lookarounds:

```
>>> s = "12.03 5.897 7.10.74 0.103 12.05 6.4.1 8.98"
>>> print re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\b\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.)', s)
['12.03', '5.897', '0.103', '12.05', '8.98']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFgPui/4)

- `(?<!\.)` is negative lookbehind to assert failure when previous char is DOT.
- `(?!\.)` is negative lookahead to assert failure when next char is DOT.
- `\b` is word boundary which is required on both sides to make sure we match full decimal number

Comment: That's exactly what i want. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Ha. If I ever see someone write this in code I'm working on, they'll find themselves with a nasty email! ;) +1 for explanation.

Comment: This is interesting. Learned something about regex today. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Regex solution:**

First split the string into list using:

Then use `re` lib to use regex

```
s = "12.03 5.897 7.10.74 0.103 12.05 6.4.1 8.98";
sList= s.split();
#d+ strats with one or more digits follwd by a .(dot) ends with one or more digits;
r = re.compile('^\d+\.\d+$');
filter(r.match, sList);
```

If you want pure regex solution try this: (Note untested)

```
myMatch = tuple(re.finditer(r"(\d+\.\d+)\s|$", s))

for str in myMatch :
    print str.group()
```

**EDIT** As per `@erip` comment you can add `[-+]?` to your regex `[-+]?(\d+\.\d+)\s|$` if you have signed values in your string.

Comment: Might want to add `[-+]?` to your regex in case of negatives or stray positives. +1

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to solve this without spliting the string first?

Answer (score 2):

Use `(?<=\s)\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)|^\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)`:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)|^\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)', s)

# ['12.03', '5.897', '0.103', '12.05', '8.98']
```

- the patten matches either `(?<=\s)\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)` or `^\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)` depending on whether the number is at the beginning of the string;
- `\d*\.\d*(?=\s|$)` matches a number with one dot followed by a space or the end of the string;

Note: Can not use `(?<=\s|^)` to integrate both cases because the look-behind syntax does not support so;

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "12.03 5.897 7.10.74 0.103 12.05 6.4.1 8.98"
r = re.compile('^\d+\.\d+$')
res = filter(r.match, string.split(' '))
print res
```