# gsub: replace word if not wrapped in brackets

Tags: r, regex

I would like to `gsub` a word, but only cases where it is not wrapped in brackets.

```
x <- c("hello","[hello]")
```

I would like `gsub(regex,"test",x)` to return `c("test","[hello]")`, but I am having trouble creating the correct regex statement.

A naive implementation is: `gsub("^(?!\\[).*$","test",x, perl=TRUE)`, which works in the above case, but only because each string is one word, so it doesn't work for `x <- "hello [hello]"` for example, which I want to be `test [hello]`.

I've tried a bunch of different lookaheads to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Input

```
x <- c("hello", "[hello]", "hello [hello]")
```

Desired

```
# [1] "test"         "[hello]"      "test [hello]"
```

Comment: Well what *is* your desired output for the second example?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point. I made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative look around to set constraint to the word boundaries, for instance `(?<!\\[)\\b\\w+\\b(?!\\])` will replace words only if the word boundary is not `[]`:

```
gsub("(?<!\\[)\\b\\w+\\b(?!\\])", "test", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "test [hello]"       # assuming this is your desired output
```

---

`\\b\\w+\\b` will look for a word but with negative look-behind `?<!` and negative look-ahead `?!`, the word boundary should not be `[]`. You can also reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835997/how-to-write-python-expression-to-filter-out-certain-strings/40836068#40836068).

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `grep`

```
x[grep("^[^[]+$", x)] <- "test"
x
#[1] "test"    "[hello]"
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub("^[^[]+", "test", x)
#[1] "test"    "[hello]"
```

---

For the second case

```
sub("^\\b[^[+]+\\b", "test", x1)
#[1] "test [hello]"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("hello","[hello]")
x1 <- "hello [hello]"
```